# isset is not checking the script

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<form method="POST" action="home.php">
User: <br><input type="text" name="username" size="40"/><br /> 
Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" size="40"/><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('cheapbooks');
    echo "connected to DB";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' ");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];
        }
        if($username == $dbuser && $password == $dbpass)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;
            echo "Logged in successfully";
            //header("Location: home.php"); //Redirecting to home page after login
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed........";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "NO Action!!!";
}
?>
```

I have written this code for creating login form. When I open the form in browser, it displays "No Action!!!!" which is the statement in last else. I cant figure out the error, why it isnt checking if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: When you first load the page, before the form is posted, `$_POST` is not defined. So, `isset($_POST['submit'])` is false and your "No Action" message is displayed.

Comment: One more very typical example that should show everyone to finally stop that stupid habit of placing form and processing logic in the same script. Don't! It only creates problems!

Comment: Preach on Brother @arkascha! Preach on!

Comment: remove `else` part either or put your form processing logic to different script

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*`, it's deprecated sinds php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the php part as when the form loads it checks the isset($_POST['submit']) when the form is not yet submitted so you will see no action.
Create a login.php file and put this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<form method="POST" action="home.php">
User: <br><input type="text" name="username" size="40"/><br /> 
Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" size="40"/><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Next in the same folder create another file named home.php and put the php  code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('cheapbooks');
    echo "connected to DB";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' ");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];
        }
        if($username == $dbuser && $password == $dbpass)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;
            echo "Logged in successfully";
            //header("Location: home.php"); //Redirecting to home page after login
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed........";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "NO Action!!!";
}
?>
```

when you open login.php you will get the form and when you post it it will redirect to home.php file. You can do whatever stuff you want in home.php.
Also I suggest you to use either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) they are more safe.

Comment: Another file is not ```required``` it can be with the same file. mention the two option.

Comment: @xdevnull It can be but it is not good to have. Its better to keep form and processing separate

Answer (score 0):

The `isset($_POST['submit'])` clearly saying,

> Is this page contains `$_POST` (that contains 'submit' key) or no?

If the answer is yes, it shows your logic, otherwise the `"NO Action!!!"` part. You should know, it will always check for the **content** of `$_POST` whether it's set or no. And for what you're looking at is, the request method of the page giving out. Since you're telling the page to listen to `$_POST` method in order to show the logic (and not what it's/key containing), you're expression should be

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*ok*/
}else{
    /*No action*/
}
```

It's now saying

> Is this page contains `$_POST` (that contains 'submit' key) and the request method is post or no?

And like other suggests, separating files (I actually mean *purposes*), is always better.